# Having optional parameters as parent state in ui-router

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some states in my Angular app, both having `myParent` as parent state:

```
var myChild1 = {
  name: 'myChild1',
  parent: 'myParent',
  url: '/mychild1'
  ...
};

var myChild2 = {
  name: 'myChild2',
  parent: 'myParent',
  url: '/mychild2'
  ...
};
```

and here's `myParent`

```
var myParent = {
  name: 'myParent',
  abstract: true,
  url: '/:username/:password',
  resolve: {
    authorized: [
      myService,
      '$stateParams',
      function (myService, $stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);

        myService.doSomething() // unrelated
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want to access it like the following:

`/mychild1/superman/superpassword`

However, it's only letting me access it like so:

`/superman/superpassword/mychild1`

If I do it the second way, I can't make the parameters optional. I don't think my solution's correct in the sense. How can I make the parameters optional for all children? (I know I could define the params in the `url` for every child, but that's not good practice)

** Btw, I know this is not proper authentication.. it's just an example I am using at the moment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access it like `/mychild1/superman/superpassword`, you need to have both of those parameters on the child states, like you mentioned:

```
var myChild1 = {
  name: 'myChild1',
  parent: 'myParent',
  url: '/mychild1/:username/:password'
  ...
};
```

If you don't want to write that multiple times (so that you can keep your logic in one place -- you're correct about repetitive code not being a good practice), you can create yourself a helper function, like so:

```
function generateChildUrl(name) {
  return name + '/:username/:password';
}

var myChild1 = {
  name: 'myChild1',
  parent: 'myParent',
  url: generateChildUrl('/mychild1')
  ...
};
```